# App returns 404 when deployed to production server

Tags: reactjs, apache, server, routes, react-router

My react app is working fine in local, but when I deploy it to a development server I cannot hit the refresh bar. If I do, it will immediately throw a 404 not found error. I cannot manually navigate using the address bar.

I have tried modifying the `.htaccess` file in the server. still no luck. I tried tinkering with the router adding `browserhistory` and stuff and still no luck. I understand this has something to do with `client side routing`. This is the `.htaccess` file I'm currently using

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

This is the generic code I'm using in `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route,Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Backup from "./forms/backup_request/backupRequest";
import Restoration from "./forms/restoration_request/RestorationRequest";
import AssetRequest from "./forms/new_asset_request/AssetRequest";

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
<div>
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
<Route path="/backup_request" component={Backup} />
<Route path="/restoration_request" component={Restoration}/>
<Route path="/new_asset_request" component={AssetRequest} />
</div>
</Switch>
)
}
}
```

This is the error message displayed

`Not Found
The requested URL /id_request was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it. it was a serverside error. needed configuring on the apache server to accept the `.htaccess` file.